# Adding lines to grouped boxplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, boxplot

I have a dataset with 3 factors (Parent.organization, Hierarchy, variable) as well as a metric variable (value) and could use some help. Here is some sample data of the same style:

```
sampleData <- data.frame(id = 1:100, 
Hierarchy = sample(c("Consultant", "Registrar", "Intern", "Resident"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                     Parent.organization = sample(c("Metropolitan", "Regional"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                     variable = sample(c("CXR", "AXR", "CTPA", "CTB"), 100, replace = TRUE),
                     value = rlnorm(20, log(10), log(2.5)))
summary(sampleData)
```

Using the following code I get the graph below

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

p0 = ggplot(sampleData, aes(x = Hierarchy, y = value, fill = variable)) +
  geom_boxplot() 
plog = p0 + scale_y_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x),
                      labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  theme_bw() +
 facet_grid(.~Parent.organization, scales = "free", space = "free")
```

[image]

I have a set of values I want to mark for each scan variable (these are the same across all elements of the hierarchy and represent true values). Lets say they are 3, 5, 7, 5 for AXR, CTB, CTPA, CXR respectively. I want these overlayed on top but I am unsure how to proceed.

I'm after something akin to (I've just filled the first two but the same pattern would apply across the board):

[image]

My knowledge of R is improving but I'd say I'm still fairly inept. Also any suggestions on how to improve my question are also very welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to make new data frame for the lines, where you have the same grouping and facetting variables as in original data frame. All the data should be repeated for the all combinations.

```
true.df<-data.frame(Hierarchy =rep(rep(c("Consultant", "Registrar", "Intern", "Resident"),each=4),times=2),
                    Parent.organization = rep(c("Metropolitan", "Regional"),each=16),
                    variable = rep(c("AXR", "CTB", "CTPA", "CXR"),times=8),
                    true.val=rep(c(3,5,7,5),times=8))
```

Then you can use `geom_crossbar()` to add the lines. Use `true.val` for the `y`, `ymin` and `ymax` to get lines. `position=position_dodge()` will ensure that lines are dodged and `show_guide=FALSE` will ensure that legend isn't affected.

```
plog+geom_crossbar(data=true.df,aes(x = Hierarchy,y=true.val,ymin=true.val,
                                    ymax=true.val,fill=variable),
                   show_guide=FALSE,position=position_dodge(),color="red")
```

[image]

Comment: That's fantastic. That's taught me few things in one go. Thanks!